# Do you know where I can get a Brick Vac?

Tags: organisation

I am in dire need of a Brick Vac.  The 2 boys 5 and 7 are building daily, but still have plenty of strays on the floor and the end of the day. With the growing popularity of Lego City building sets, along with Star Wars sets and Legos in general, we need to get Lego to start making the Brick Vac again, to save on mom and Gramma's feet. !

Answer (score 1):

If you really want one, these can still be acquired on Bricklink:

http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?itemID=45363